# What's the correct way to treat numbers in snake case?

Tags: naming-conventions, case-conversion, snakecasing

If I want to write a phrase like "Column 1" in snake case (the usual C way of formatting identifiers that looks like `some_function`), do I insert underscore between a word or a number, like `column_1`, or not, like `column1`?

That may be a painfully trivial question, but I haven't been able to find a snake case definition that would answer this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have only ever encountered specific documentation on this topic in one place - the **Rubocop Ruby Style Guide** (https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars-with-numbers)

It's probably safe to say there is not a clear winner in one approach over the other. One could also argue that the premise of the format is that: for a given string, all letters are lowercase and all spaces become underscores. By that standard you wouldn't format something `column1` unless it started out as Column1.

Personally I prefer `column_1` approach.

I find it easier to read, and easier to execute batch find/replace regex queries or to make multi-line edits in my text editor.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to cite [Rust naming conventions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/style/naming/README.html):

> In snake_case or SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE, a "word" should never consist
>   of a single letter unless it is the last "word". So, we have btree_map
>   rather than b_tree_map, but **PI_2** rather than PI2.

So write `column_1`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a code-searching tool (e.g. [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)), you can probe a codebase to compare the use of both conventions so your choice can match closely your favorite language/libraries.

Here is a comparison on [CPython 3.12](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.12) codebase:

```bash
# Underscored numbered variable name suffixes frequency
$ ag --python --stats-only '\W[a-z]_1 ='
1 matches
1 files contained matches
1963 files searched

# Not underscored numbered variable name suffixes frequency
$ ag --python --stats-only '\W[a-z]1 ='
863 matches
199 files contained matches
1963 files searched
```

So in Python it seems that **not using an underscore** (`column1`) is the convention.

Thanks @eliotsykes for the [original idea](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide/issues/606#issuecomment-258419057).